# pip not found fresh Kali Linux installed

Tags: kali-linux, python, pip

My Fresh kali Linux install doesn't find pip and so i can't run my scripts.
So here is what i tried:

```
kali# pip -V
Command not found

kali# whereis pip 
pip:

kali# locate pip | grep /usr/bin
/usr/bin/lesspipe
/usr/bin/pipal

kali# apt-search python-pip
python-pip-whl

kali# apt install python-pip-whl
python-pip-whl is already installed
```

I also tried to add ubuntu repos with the package python-pip. But didn't work.
Sooo….yeah. Nothing really helps. Can somebody plz help me? I use kali for like one year and this is the first time this happens to me :D 
What am i missing? Somebody can explain to me?
Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 went [end-of-life](https://pythonclock.org/) on January 1, 2020.  According to this article, Debian (and Kali as a downstream consumer) will be [removing Python 2 packages](https://www.kali.org/news/python-2-end-of-life/).  While Python 2 `pip` is not explicitly discussed, it's entirely likely that's why you can't find it.

Instead, you can `apt install python3-pip` and use `pip3` to install packages for any coding you do, which should be in Python 3 rather than Python 2.

Comment: Thx a lot!.. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

If `pip` not found, try these commands:

1. `sudo apt install python3-pip`
2. `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
3. `/usr/local/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip`